# CSS3 border-radius background overlap

Tags: css

In a rounded-corner container I want the first div to be of another background color from the other divs. The problem I have is that the background of the first div overlaps the rounded corner. I did a test to show the problem: http://www.webdevout.net/test?025 The problem occurs in Chrome and FF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you'll need to give your inner div `box-header-bug` a top-left and top-right border radius:

```
-moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
```

Comment: The issue is inheritance, no need to define the values again.

Comment: @mystrdat While your answer is technically correct, in practice, it doesn't work as expected. See my comment on your post.

Answer (score 2):

add the following lines to your box-header-bug class

```
border-radius: inherit;
-moz-border-radius: inherit;
```

UPDATE:

```
border-top-left-radius: inherit;
border-top-right-radius: inherit;
```

Comment: Using `inherit` in this case, will bring in the bottom border radiuses too, which I assume is undesirable.

Comment: Well, the idea is to inherit from the container, so we don't have to pass values. However, I have updated the code so it reflects your concerns.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as the issue is simple CSS inheritance.

Comment: Actually, this only seems to work as expected if you inherit all 4 border radius. If you choose to inherit only the top/bottom border radius, for instance, then there appears to be a problem. http://jsfiddle.net/Zw6kc/1/ I would suggest still setting the child element's border radius as I have suggested.

Comment: Inheriting specific properties works for me, important to say I only tried it in Chrome/FF so far.